# Two before_action on one method. Which before_action will be called first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Requests controller:

```html
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_request, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :handle_payment, :close_request, :handle_procedure_payment ]
  before_action :is_closed, only: [:edit,:update]
                                                
end
```

as you can see I have set_request and is_closed methods to run before :edit and :update methods at the same time. In my set request I define @request variable, and i is_closed I also need this variable to be defined

```html
@request = Request.find(params[:id])
```

For example i get called :edit, so will my :set_request run before :is_closed so that when :is_closed is run @request is already defined? 
Generally, how do we define multiple methods to run before some action.

Answer (score 1):

The way you define is fine. In this approach your

> :set_request

is always called first then it call second before action method

> :is_closed